# How to check who can su to my user

Tags: linux, sudo, users, su

I have lot of users and sudoers is set based on groups. Is there a way I can check which user can su to my user?

Like :

```
sudo su - myuser
```

I tried grep my /etc/group file, but it’s not giving me the correct result.
"id" command also gives too many results to check manually.

Comment: /etc/sudoers and /etc/sudo.d/* ?

Answer (score 2):

root can switch user to any username or check for below entry in `/etc/sudoers`. if its found then that particular user can switch user to your username

```
username ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
username ALL=(ALL:ALL) /usr/bin/sudo  /bin/su Yourusername
username ALL=(ALL:ALL) /usr/bin/sudo  /bin/su
```

Answer (score 0):

All user with superuser privilege can do so. Superuser privilege is assigned using the file `/etc/sudoers` , and any file inside  `/etc/sudoers.d/` provided the directory is included in `/etc/sudoers` file.

Open the file `/etc/sudoers`. All user rights and corresponding formats are mentioned there. Check for users having special privileges. Repeat the same process for any file inside the `/etc/sudoers.d` directory